# Force an input control to always show the value it is bound to

Tags: angular, typescript

My component looks like this:

```
@Component({
  template: `
  <form>
    <label>Enter your name:</label>
    <input #name name="name" [ngModel]="firstName" (change)="onNameChange(name.value)">
  </form>
  <p>Your name: {{firstName}}</p>`
})
export class AppComponent {
  firstName = 'John';

  onNameChange(value: string): void {
    if (value == "") {
      this.firstName = "John";
    }
    else {
      this.firstName = value;
    }
  }
}
```

If the users erases all text and then leaves the input control, the input control does not go back to the default text *John* as I expected. I understand that this is because the model never actually changed.

How can I get the input control to always shows the current exact value of the model?

Here is the [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/YSv3j1iz612lNZIhjLif?p=preview) of this issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to get access to `FormControl`, from [the docs](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/forms/index/NgModel-directive.html):

> If you wish to inspect the properties of the associated FormControl
>   (like validity state), you can also export the directive into a local
>   template variable using ngModel as the key (ex: #myVar="ngModel"). You
>   can then access the control using the directive's control property

So, update template to this:

```
<input #name name="name" [ngModel]="firstName" #m="ngModel" (change)="onNameChange(name.value, m.control)">
```

And then update form control using [standard API](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/forms/index/FormControl-class.html):

```
  onNameChange(value: string, ctrl): void {
    if (value == "") {
      ctrl.setValue('John');
```

See [the plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/bizjfh1SrzZglCZ1ZNq5?p=preview).

This is effectively the same what the `ngModel` directive is doing. [See the sources](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/forms/src/directives/ng_model.ts#L214).

Comment: I am sorry about that. I also noticed the error right after posting the question and updated the Plunker. It should work now.

Comment: Thank you @Maximus. This was the answer I was looking for. My conclusion of you answer is that you cannot automatically make the binding refresh its value if the change detection has not spotted a change. In the cases where the model has not changed, but the input control isn´t reflecting the model, you need to programmatically set the input controls value as you have shown. If you have many controls, you may instead want to do `this.form.resetForm(this.model);` given that your controls are named identical with the fields in the model.

Comment: @coder925, yes, `resetForm` will update control as well. But it also updates  `pristine` and `touched` statuses, and runs validators. Don't forget you can upvote my answer if helped :)

Answer (score 0):

The following will change the model if you remember

> "Banana in the Box"

```html
<input #name name="name" [(ngModel)]="firstName" (change)="onNameChange(name.value)">
```

Comment: Thank you, your suggestion solves the issue! Unfortunately, in my real scenario I am not allowed to update the model directly with a two-way binding. Can you think of any other way to accomplish the same result by keeping the binding one-way?

Comment: If you tell me which way.

Comment: I need to keep the binding one-way as in `[ngModel]="firstName"` (from model to control).